# How many Marvel films can be expected?

Tags: marvel

I wonder how many Marvel films could be expected around the "Avengers subject" given the multiple post-credits scenes we already have seen.

We already have 2 Infinity Stones after Thor 2 : The Dark World
So, at least 5 more films could be expected. Then, for 6 Soul Gems, we could expect another 6.

Is it possible to take a guess on how many films we could have around the "Avenger" subject ?

Comment: My answer would be, Infinity.

Comment: As long as they generate angel dust and escort money, they'll keep popping them out

Comment: @MrLister and beyond!

Comment: You might as well ask "How many action movies can we expect?" There won't be a definitive answer to this one.

Comment: MCU has already got 3 Infinity Stone (latest in Guardians of the Galaxy).

Comment: Yes. It is possible to take a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films), there have been about 21 confirmed release dates (including the Phase One movies, which includes everything up to and including *The Avengers*). So we're getting at least that many. Probably.

According to [this article](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2014-04-03/kevin-feige-marvels-superhero-at-running-movie-franchises), there are tentative plans stretching until 2028:

> There’s a map of films reaching far into the next decade on the wall of Feige<sup>1</sup>'s office. "It’s like looking through the Hubble telescope. You go, 'What’s happening back there? I can sort of see it,' " he laughs. "They printed out a new one recently that went to 2028."

If they keep up their current pace of about 2 per year, we could see as many as 19 more, for a whopping total of 40 MCU movies.

The true answer, though, is Mr. Lister's: Marvel will keep making movies until they stop making ludicrous amounts of money. If we all decide that, say, *Age of Ultron* is crap and stop seeing MCU movies, Marvel will release maybe one or two more, and then stop. Otherwise, we could potentially be looking at literally any number of movies over the next few years.

---

<sup>1</sup> Kevin Feige, who seems to be the guy in charge of making the MCU; he's been a producer on every movie so far

Comment: I wonder what happens if/when the actors eventually don't want to make more or can't. Will they keep making films or less-known superheroes, invent new ones, just replace the actor or replace the character (invent a new person who wears the Iron Man suit)?

Comment: If an actor refused to play a character, they'll either kill them off, write them out (Like they did with Iron Patriot) or just recast them.